In an XSLT template, I need to prefix names with a "'l" if they start with a vowel
In the XSLT template I will expand an input variable like this:
<xsl:value-of select="$ClubName" />
But if that $ClubName starts with a vowel, I need to prefix with l'
I think there may be a regular expression technique to do this.

Define "vowel".

In xslt 1.0 you could try this:
  <xsl:if test="contains('AEIOUaeiou',substring($ClubName,1,1))">
    <xsl:text>l'</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="$ClubName"/>


Try:
<xsl:value-of select="replace($ClubName, '^([aeiou])', 'l$1', 'i')"/>

Of course, this assumes your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher.
